# Getting an error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" for the string palindrome program in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am writing below program to check if the string is palindrome or not but at line "l = len(s)" it is giving me an error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

```
s = input("Enter a string to check: ")
l = len(s) 
counter = 0

for i in range(0,int(l/2)):
        if s[i] == s[-1-i]:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            counter = 0
            break

if counter == int(l/2):
    print("Palindrome")
else:
    print("Not a palindrome")
```

Comment: This snippet runs properly on my computer. `len`'s probably been redefined, as per Jindra and Solomon's answers.

Comment: Also, since you're only dealing with positive integers, you can replace `int(a/b)` with `a//b`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/#semantics-of-floor-division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you re-defined the `len` builtin.

As bad practice as it is, you can still solve this by writing

```
l = s.__len__()
```

Comment: Your solutions worked but I am not able to understand that where did I re-defined the len builtin and len(string) gives an integer so why can't I assign it to a variable "l"? (This is all the code I have written.)

Comment: @DipenBakraniya Somehow `len` has been set to an integer. How it happened we can't tell, because whatever did it is not shown in your code.

Comment: @DipenBakraniya try running the code in the ipython console, or on a clean python installation somewhere. You can also print out the value of `len`. It should say ``<built-in function len>``

Comment: @JindraHelcl My code worked, I restarted the kernel (I am using jupyter notebook IDE) and re-run the code. Thanks for the help. Between what is the difference between underscored len()  and len()?

Comment: `len(x)` is a Python built-in method that calls the function `__len__` of the object `x`. So you can override/implement the `__len__` method of a class to provide the functionality on custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

In your program, do you ever assign to `len`? If so, that's probably the issue. Use a different variable name to avoid overwriting the builtin and causing these sorts of issues.

Comment: No, this is all the code I have written. I am not assigning len anywhere else.